# Counterintuitive results for dplyr::between() when using vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

When using `dplyr::between()`, I assumed that it would compare each element. However it seems like that is not the case, as shown in the below example.

```
x <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
y <- c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.052, -0.3)
z <- c(0.43, 0.52, 0.0, 0.76, 0.85, 0.83)

dplyr::between(x=x, left=y, right=z)

# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

For example, in the 3rd element, 0.2 is not between 0.0 and 0.0, but TRUE is returned.
In the 4th element, 0.5 is between 0.052 and 0.85, but FALSE is returned.

Any ideas on what causes this behavior?

Comment: The left and right arguments are not meant to be vectorized, so they just take the first elements (0, 0.43). See here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::between` only accepts single value in `left` and `right`, it cannot work with vector of values.

The behaviour that you expect is present in `data.table::between` :

```
x <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
y <- c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.052, -0.3)
z <- c(0.43, 0.52, 0.0, 0.76, 0.85, 0.83)
data.table::between(x=x, lower=y, upper=z)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, this is easier with comparison  operators and is flexible

```
x >= y & x <= z
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
x <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
y <- c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.052, -0.3)
z <- c(0.43, 0.52, 0.0, 0.76, 0.85, 0.83)
```